# Trying to identify this sword. Think early 20th century. Maybe ceremonial

Tags: india

[image][image][image][image].  Scabbard and handle are wood. Scabbard has2of 3 bands possibly brass. Blade has markings in 2 locations, designs are similar. Has hallmark design on bottom of guard, which may be brass, also. Seems more ceremonial. Thinking maybe n. African, or maybe middle eastern. Possibly mossback or Mongolian? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me to be of Thai or Burmese design - similar to the [krabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krabi%E2%80%93krabong) or [dha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dha_(sword)).  I base my opinion on the scabbard, hilt design, and overall blade shape.  Although many examples of these types do not have much of a cross guard the two below have similar ones to yours.
[image: dha]
Image from: [Mount Castle Antiques](http://mountcastlesantiques.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=13)
[image: krabi]
Image from: [I stock photos](http://www.istockphoto.com/photo/thai-swords-isolated-on-white-background-thai-swords-isolated-gm654276412-118968815)

Comment: Looks good, some more info [here](http://www.vikingsword.com/ubb/Forum1/HTML/001291.html)